# Как исправить ошибку с json?

Tags: python, json

Сама ошибка:

```
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Я догадываюсь,что она связана с некорректным ответом сервера.Я делал проверку на r.status_code,но даже когда статус был нормальным(200),мне выдает эту ошибку.Подскажите, как это можно исправить,и являются ли мои догадки хоть чуть-чуть правдивыми?
Правка

json ответ:`{'success': False, 'error': 'nothing'}`

обычный:{"success":false,"error":"nothing"}

Comment: Проверить, что приходит в теле ответа. Может быть, Вас вычисляют и отдают не json

Comment: Вы имеете в виду response?

Comment: Да (r.content или r.text)

Comment: Ответ всегда одинаковый

Comment: И я не использую r.text т.к использую .json()

Comment: Просто спустя примерно 30 минут работы,скрипт выдает ошибку

Comment: Вот и используйте r.text или r.content, чтобы выяснить, почему .json() не работает. А сейчас это гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: Ну вообще-то мне нужен именно json

Comment: Ну вообще-то он у вас не работает, поэтому используйте r.text или r.content, чтобы выяснить, почему .json() не работает

Comment: Тогда как мне сравнивать элементы диктов?

Comment: Ну так через .json() и сравнивайте. Но для этого нужно, чтобы .json() работал, а чтобы выяснить, почему он у вас не работает, используйте r.text или r.content

Comment: Так в этом треде я и пытаюсь узнать,почему возникает трейсбек

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос находится в r.text или r.content

Comment: @artemso72 Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос содержимое `r.text`. Скорее всего, это не `json`-валидная структура, поэтому и возникает ошибка при попытке одноимённым методом распарсить её.

Comment: Правку сделал,посмотрите

Comment: Когда ошибка в json r.text выводит ту же строку

Comment: Кое как нашел,что r.text выводит это:
<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.3</center>
</body>
</html>
как это можно исключить?